# Remove App icon background

Tags: xiaomi, app-icons

[image]

I have a Xiaomi mi5 (MIUI 8) and I would like to remove the white background of these icon but I don't know if It is possibile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BY9VLrcBPjNjY3eXhkQ25aMHM/view

From above link download a .mtz file(theme file)
and apply that theme.

You need a designer account to apply third party themes

Signup for designer account at http://designer.xiaomi.com

It takes 24 hrs for designer account verification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't own a Xiaomi device, but on my Samsung J5 I have the option to remove those background at **Settings > Displays > Icon frame**. Check to see if there is something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can download another launcher from the PlayStore that looks like you want it.

There are many launcher that look like the one from MIUI and even more themes.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using nova launcher and apply the Android stock icon pack from the look and feel option in settings. It will remove the backgrounds in the icons. Alternatively, you can try using some icon packs if you are not a fan of the stock circle icons. I made a list of popular icon packs for Android on my website. Check them out [Top 5 Android Icon Packs](http://reviewdeeper.com/2017/07/top-5-android-icon-packs-for-july-2017.html)