# Switching app icon background from white back to transparent

Tags: miui, app-icons, themes

I'm using a Xiaomi phone running Android 6.0.1 MMB29M with MIUI global version 8.5.3.0 (MALMIED). A while ago I foolishly tried out some of the themes available by default, then hoped to switch back. That didn't really work, in the sense that no matter what I now do, the app icons now have a white background instead of the transparency many of them used to have.

How can I enable app icon transparency again?

**Edit:** I've looked at

[Remove App icon background](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175514/remove-app-icon-background?rq=1)

and tried to use the first solution suggested there, but it's not clear to me how to install a .mtz file; the theme settings doesn't allow it, nor does double-clicking the .mtz in the file explorer.

Notes:

- I'm hoping for an easy solution of course, but I won't hesitate to SSH into that sucker and edit stuff manually if need be.
- If you need additional information, ask in the comments.
- I don't have a Google Play account nor an account with Xiaomi, and would like to keep it that way if possible :-(